# Get every nth item starting at nth position

Tags: c#, linq

I am using LINQ to get the nth value of a list using the code below

```
var addMixingEvent
    = productionEvent.OrderBy(x => x.StartTime)
                     .Where((x, i) => i % mixesRequired == 0)
                     .ToList();
```

This works to an extent, but I also need the first item that is brought back and added to my list to be that nth item.

I have changed 0 to be mixesRequired, and in this instance the value of this is 4.

So in essence I need every 4th item, and the first item to be added be that 4th item.

Any and all help appreciated.

Thanks

Simon

Comment: Do you just need `(i + 1) % mixesRequired`?

Comment: Simply compute `i % mixesRequired` for each index and print it out, and look at the items you actually want to get.  It should then be pretty clear what you need to do to get the ones that you want.

Comment: @Rawling In this instance I need to get to every 4th item in a list starting at the 4th item

Comment: `.Skip(4).Where((x, i) => (i + 1) % mixesRequired == 0)`

Comment: @john That's starting at the 6th item.

Comment: @Servy If `mixesRequired` is 2...

Comment: Could you give an example of desired input and output?

Comment: @Rawling sorry, the 8th; still not correct though.

Comment: @Codor it would be quite difficult to because its a list of a class that im working with, but what I have is a list of x amount, in this instance its a list of 15 items, so i need to get every 4th item in the list, starting at position 4 which is the variable mixesRequired and then get a value from it

Comment: @SimonPrice just construct a generic list of numbers for your example input and explain which numbers will be in the output. Noone cares what you do with the resulting list of every n-th item.

Comment: using an adaptation of the comment from @john I believe I have it now, I didnt event consider skip, dont know why as I was using it heavily earlier today.  John, if you would like to post your comment as an answer I would gladly accept it as the correct one as you answered before any given answers

Comment: @SimonPrice You *really* should actually work out what you want for your desired input and output.  If you actually take the time to write out a single example it will make it *very* clear what's wrong.  Note that when creating a minimal reproducible example you can remove code not related to the question that you're asking, so in this case, the classes in the list aren't actually important; you can just create a list of strings or numbers as an example.

Comment: @SimonPrice Also, I still believe user Rawling gave the correct solution.

Comment: Don't understand what you mean by "first item to be added be that 4th item". can you please just list the indexes of the items you want? Or explain it differently?

Comment: @SimonPrice Feel free to post it yourself since you reached the full solution :)

Answer (score 2):

If understood correctly, you want to get every nth item, skipping the item in position 0.

If your ordered sequence of items was the following:

```
var orderedItems = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13 }
```

and you wanted every 4th item skipping the item in position 0, your desired output would be as follows:

```
var filteredItems = { 4, 8, 12 }
```

If this is ok, you can achieve that filtered output in several ways. e.g:

```
var filteredItems = orderedItems.Skip(mixesRequired).Where((x,i) => i % mixesRequired == 0);
```

or

```
var filteredItems = orderedItems.Where((x,i) => i > 0 && i % mixesRequired == 0);
```

or

```
var filteredItems = orderedItems.Where((x,i) => i % mixesRequired == 0).Skip(1);
```

Don't believe any of this alternatives is noticeable better than the others. In any case, a quick profiling may clear your doubts.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Skip() method before your ToList() statement to skip the first result.

Your code should look like this:

```
var addMixingEvent
= productionEvent.OrderBy(x => x.StartTime)
                 .Where((x, i) => i % mixesRequired == 0)
                 .Skip(1)
                 .ToList();
```

[Enumerable.Skip](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: This is returning the list of items who's index number matches the `mixesRequired` but as programmers we know that the item position and the index numbers differ by `1`... however, it remains a mystery whether this is the solution as long as the original question author doesn't clarify